# Localstack: Function already exists/ResourceConflictException

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose, localstack

My deploy to localstack running in Docker (deploy is made via `serverless-localstack`) fails every time. With version 0.11.1 it worked after 3-5 attempts (without changing anything) and with the latest version there is no change to get the whole stack deployed to localstack. My localstack docker image is the latest.

Deploying **one or two functions alone works** when the rest is commented out.
It works even if I change the handler of all functions to a simple handler like in some serverless examples. So with an increasing size of the package, the error seems to come up.

My first guess was that there are some timeouts while deploying because the complete package size is relatively big for eight functions and the deployment takes quite long. Another observation: When the error comes, there are 1-2 functions and the resources/streams already deployed but not accessible. Tried to give docker some more resources but that did not help either.

Errors from localstack:

```
Running CloudFormation stack deployment loop iteration 1
localstack_1        | 2020-05-30T20:31:40:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Currently processing stack resource api-dev-dev/GraphQLMainHandlerLambdaVersionOcnwJH5Fo772wd6pU0oM5FhOPeqfRUzVOcuaYd1Oizk: None
localstack_1        | 2020-05-30T20:31:40:DEBUG:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Currently processing stack resource api-dev-dev/GraphQLMainHandlerLambdaFunction: True
localstack_1        | 2020-05-30T20:31:40:ERROR:localstack.services.cloudformation.cloudformation_starter: Unable to parse and create resource "GraphQLMainHandlerLambdaVersionOcnwJH5Fo772wd6pU0oM5FhOPeqfRUzVOcuaYd1Oizk": 'FunctionName' Traceback (most recent call last):


Unable to parse and create resource "GraphQLMainHandlerLambdaFunction": An error occurred (ResourceConflictException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Function already exist: api-dev-dev-graphQLMainHandler Traceback (most recent call last)
...
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceConflictException: An error occurred (ResourceConflictException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Function already exist: api-dev-dev-graphQLMainHandler
```

+Many more with the same reasons.

serverless.yaml:

```
service:
  name: api-${self:provider.stage}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'eu-central-1'}
  profile: dev-local
  environment:
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    MAIN_TABLE_NAME: ${self:custom.mainTableName}
    MAIN_BUCKET_NAME: ${self:custom.mainBucketName}
    #MAIN_TABLE_STREAM_ARN:
      #Fn::GetAtt:
        #- MainTable
        #- StreamArn
    #DYNAMODB_REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    #AWS_PROFILE: ${self:provider.profile}
    AWS_REGION: ${self:provider.region}

package:
  include:
    - src/**

functions:
 graphQLMainHandler:
   handler: src/handler/graphQLMainHandler.graphQLMainHandler
   events:
     - http:
         method: post
         path: graphql-main
         cors: true
 dynamoDBStreamHandler:
   handler: src/handler/dynamoDBStreamHandler.dynamoDBStreamHandler
   events:
     - stream:
         type: dynamodb
         arn:
           Fn::GetAtt:
             - MainTable
             - StreamArn
         batchSize: 10
         startingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
 pictureHandler:
   handler: src/handler/pictureHandler.pictureHandler
   events:
     - http:
         method: get
         path: picture
         cors: true
 taskHandler:
   handler: src/handler/taskHandler.taskHandler
 updateMainTableElasticsearchMappings:
   handler: src/handler/dev.updateMainTableElasticsearchMappings
 createMainTableElasticsearchIndex:
   handler: src/handler/dev.createMainTableElasticsearchIndex
 analysisTaskRunner:
   handler: src/handler/taskRunner.analysisTaskRunner
 sendNotificationsTaskRunner:
   handler: src/handler/taskRunner.sendNotificationsTaskRunner

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-localstack
  - serverless-offline
resources:
  Resources:
    MainTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.mainTableName}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
    MainBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.mainBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedMethods:
                - GET
              AllowedOrigins:
                - "*"
              AllowedHeaders:
                - "*"

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 3000
  webpack:
    packager: yarn
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
  localstack:
    debug: true
    stages:
      - dev
    autostart: false
    #lambda:
      #mountCode: false

  mainTableName: main-${self:provider.stage}
  mainBucketName: main-${self:provider.stage}
```

docker-compose.dev.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  localstack:
    privileged: true
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
      - DEBUG=1
      - COMPOSE_PARALLEL_LIMIT=100
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - USE_SSL=1
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    ports:
      - "4566-4599:4566-4599"

(...)
```

Comment: could you relax the strict binding of ports and try again. like  just write "4566-4599" and not "4566-4599:4566-4599"

Comment: @DeepakKharpuriya Hi! That leads to a connection refused error.